# HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User has sometimes null fields (but itself User is not a null)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I have got problem with one of helpers in my project (ASP.NET Core 7 MVC with standard MS AspNetCore.Identity authentication)

DI contains:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Helper class:

```
public HelperClassSample(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

// ... unrelatable code ...

var x = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
```

The problem is, that `x` is **never** null, but in **some cases** does not contain any data in `ClaimsPrincipal`. If I run the app, log out, then log in, and restart browser - everything is fine, there are proper `ClaimsPrincipals` in `x`.

But after another reset/rebuild, problem with empty `ClaimsPrincipal` occurs. What can be the problem?

I cannot use `HttpContext` from base .NET controller, since the problem occurs in a class which is not a controller. This class (`HelperClassSample`) is widely used throughout a lot of layers / projects in this solution

Comment: Maybe it's a timeout.

Comment: Don't use `HelperClassSample` in the first place. If your code cares about the current users and permissions, pass the user as a `ClaimsPrincipal` if not `IPrincipal` parameter. Both are base .NET objects, not tied to any stack. It's not like the request's user is going to change from layer to layer.

Comment: As for what the problem is, it's the very fact you use `AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>`. That service can't be a singleton. It represents the context of a *single* request only. In a web application there may be dozens of concurrent requests, or none at all. A hosted service for example doesn't run in response to an HTTP request so there's no HttpContext

Answer (score 1):

> the problem occurs in a class which is not a controller. This class (HelperClassSample) is widely used throughout a lot of layers/projects in this solution

Although this is the reality in that code base, this is typically a bad idea. As [the documentation for IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor) states:

> It also creates a dependency on "ambient state" which can make testing more difficult.

Not only may it make testing more difficult, but the use of Ambient Context also implies that it becomes difficult to reason about which HTTP request a particular execution thread relates to.

This may particularly be true if the code executes on a background thread.

Most likely, the problem reported in the OP is a symptom that the code executes in a context where no user is logged in.

My best advice is to keep HTTP-specific behaviour in the 'Controller layer', instead of distributing it throughout the code base.

Comment: This helper is also used by some windows services - that's why implementing http related code in controllers are not an option. Thanks for reply, i will rethink my implementation, since problem is indeed related to different context.

Comment: @guidempty even more reason to *not* use HelperClassSample. `ClaimsPrincipal` is a base .NET class, not specific to web apps. Pass that parameter around, either as-is or as the even more generic `IPrincipal`